# Oracle APEX: using APEX_IG package to manipulate IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

After upgrading APEX version I wanted to start using APEX_IG package for IG manipulation instead of using javascript.

I looked over the documentation for adding a filter and it requires to know the numeric ID for the IG which I do not have. My IG has a static ID but it is a string. How do i go about finding the region ID?

```
APEX_IG.ADD_FILTER(
p_page_id           IN NUMBER,
p_region_id         IN NUMBER,
p_filter_value      IN VARCHAR2,
p_column_name       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_operator_abbr     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
p_is_case_sensitive IN BOOLEAN  DEFAULT FALSE,
p_report_name       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to get the region id

```
select region_id 
  from apex_application_page_regions 
where page_id = YOUR_PAGE_NUMBER 
  and static_id = 'YOUR_REGION_STATIC_ID';
```

Comment: Thank you. I already found it  but you are right, that is the view to find it